# is there a better approach to this? Instead of individual click function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create show and hide with three buttons and three contents.

```
$( ".left-tab-header" ).click(function() {
                    $(".left-tab-content").toggleClass("show-tab-content");
                    $(".middle-tab-content").removeClass("show-tab-content");
                    $(".right-tab-content").removeClass("show-tab-content");
                    $(this).css("background", "#000");
                    $(".middle-tab-header").css("background","#020C15");
                    $(".right-tab-header").css("background","#020C15");
              });
     //click event for the middle-tab-header 
      $( ".middle-tab-header" ).click(function() {
                    $(".left-tab-content").removeClass("show-tab-content");
                    $(".middle-tab-content").toggleClass("show-tab-content");
                    $(".right-tab-content").removeClass("show-tab-content");
                    $(this).css("background", "#000");
                    $(".left-tab-header").css("background","#020C15");
                    $(".right-tab-header").css("background","#020C15");
              });

    // click event for the right-tab-header
     $( ".right-tab-header" ).click(function() {
                    $(".left-tab-content").removeClass("show-tab-content");
                    $(".middle-tab-content").removeClass("show-tab-content");
                    $(".right-tab-content").toggleClass("show-tab-content");
                    $(this).css("background", "#000");
                    $(".left-tab-header").css("background","#020C15");
                    $(".middle-tab-header").css("background","#020C15");
              });
```

I don't know if there is a function to simplify this. It works greatly without error. But I don't want to have individual click function with all repetitive parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way using `not(this)`  and 1 click event:

```
$( ".a, .b, .c" ).click(function() {
  $('button').not(this).removeClass('show-tab-content');
  $(this).toggleClass('show-tab-content');
});
```

You can try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/f7ur6pj8/

**Edit:**

Here is an update based on your case:

First, give another class to you 3 buttons  (exp. tab-content)

```
<button class='left-tab-content tab-content'>A</button>   
<button class='middle-tab-content tab-content'>B</button> 
<button class='right-tab-content tab-content'>C</button>
```

And for your JavaScript:

```
$( ".left-tab-content, .middle-tab-content, .right-tab-content" ).click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('show-tab-content');
  $('.tab-content').not(this).removeClass('show-tab-content');
  $(this).css("background", "#000");
  $('.tab-content').not(this).css("background","#020C15");
});
```

Comment: I can't see the name button as there are several element with buttons on the page. And more also, I am using a "div and section". However, "show-tab-content" is not for the background-colour but to display contents while the .css() is to turn on and off the background on the button-like div

Comment: This was just an example to show you how you can use different classes/elements in a single click event and how to use not(this), and for the several buttons you can give to those 3 another class (exp: tab-header) and replace $('.tab-header').not(this)